# Android 11: Cannot come back from startActivityForResult or registerForActivityResult and launch

Tags: java, android, android-11, startactivityforresult, registerforactivityresult

I have an app with a MainActivity and a SecondaryActivity.
When the MainActivity opens the SecondaryActivity, there is a situation in which I need the user to pick up a phone number from a list that is in the MainActivity.
I've used `startActivityForResult` to open back the MainActivity with an `extra` in the `intent` so that the MainActivity opens directly the fragment with the specific list, like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("UserInfo", userInfo);
intent.putExtra("SecondaryActivity", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
```

And when the user clicks on one element of that list, I set the result and finish the MainActivity in order to return to the SecondaryActivity, like this:

```java
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra(PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

That worked wonderfully until now, but I've noticed that in Android 11 devices, I have 2 problems:

1. `startActivityForResult` starts the MainActivity directly in the `onResume()` function without passing by the `onCreate()` function, as it is for Android 10 devices and below. And this forces me to check each time the MainActivity's `onResume()` function is called, if there is any `extra` sent. Thing that unnecessarily add an extra charge to the already charged MainActivity.
2. I cannot come back to the SecondaryActivity using `finish()`! Instead of that, the app is simply closed.

I've tried to use the new Activity Result APIs, and more specifically: `registerForActivityResult`, like this (in the SecondaryActivity):

```java
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            manageResult(result.getResultCode(), result.getData());
        });
}

public void onPhoneNumberClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("UserInfo", userInfo);
    intent.putExtra("SecondaryActivity", true);
    activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}
```

But, this doesn't change anything to the 2 problems that I described: `onResume()` is directly called in MainActivity and `finish()` close the app instead of closing the MainActivity and coming back to the SecondaryActivity. I understand, that the fact that the MainActivity was already opened when I use `startActivityForResult` or `registerForActivityResult` and `launch` can be the cause of those problems, but what can I do to solve them?

**Edit:**
My MainActivity is defined as `singleTask` in `AndroidManifest` and it seems that something changed in Android 11 for the management of activities defined like this. If I remove this tag, it solves the problem but I'm not sure why we defined this activity as `singleTask` and I don't want to see come back any bug that this was intended to solve...